# Python PhantomJS Flash Support

Tags: python, flash, phantomjs

I've been reading around a lot on this issue, and I have come to the conclusion that currently PhantomJS doesn't support flash anymore (version 2.0.0). How can I get around this? I need to send text to a text field that needs adobe flash present. Are there any older versions I can use? If so, how can I get that working with my project? Thanks!

Comment: Refer: http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/

Comment: How can I get the binary for windows?